# How can I start with Cocos2d-X in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x, eclipse-cdt

I'm app developer from Korea.

I want to develop Android games with Cocos2D-x in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Cocos2d-x supports XCode for Mac and Visual Studio for Windows. but they didn't support for linux users... I mean, they didn't support IDE like Eclipse,CodeBlocks for Linux..

they only provides one makefile, one cpp source code for newly created linux project..

My environment are same as followings.

```
 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 
 Eclipse CDT Kelper
 Cocos2d-x 2.2.3 Stable
```

in case of Windows, they build native C++ code in Visual Studio, and run 'natvie_build.sh' thru Cygwin then they use Eclipse with Android SDK to make APK.

question is this :

Is there any methods which can develop Cocos2D-x C++ code with EclipseCDT only?

Or is there a ready-to C++ Eclipse CDT project template for Linux?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse with C++ plugin

This links can be usesfull

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_HelloWorld_and_tests_on_linux

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Linux_Environment_Setup

Comment: You should not just post a link to the content, but also at least a brief summary of the contents, so the user can know what to expect when he goes into the links.